Disabling value validation without changing dto code | class-validator nest js
I have a dto class-validator, example attached below. Can I remove the userId from the validation without changing the code of the dto itself. For example to do this when using dto in controller
export class CreateEmployeeDto {
    @ApiProperty({ required: true })
    @IsNumber()
    @Expose()
    @Validate(RecordExistValidator, [{ model: 'Projects', property: 'id' }], {
        message: 'Project not found',
    })
    projectId: number;

    @ApiProperty({ required: true })
    @IsNumber()
    @IsOptional()
    @Expose()
    roleId?: number;

    @ApiProperty({ required: true })
    @IsNumber()
    @Expose()
    @Validate(RecordExistValidator, [{ model: 'Users', property: 'id' }], {
        message: 'User not found',
    })
    userId: number;
}

Unfortunately I didn't find a suitable solution.

You can achieve that by creating a new Dto for controller use and Apply OmitType to get all the properties excepet userId
Here's how:
export class EmployeeDto extends OmitType(CreateEmployeeDto , ['userId'] as const) {}

The OmitType() function constructs a type by picking all properties from an input type and then removing a particular set of keys. For example, suppose we start with a type like: NestJs docs
